# why my code doesn't toggle all dives while others' similar code working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am in newbie learning to code and have taken an exercise based course. My issue is the code- which is working for all-is not completely working for me.

The exercise asks for four divs that should toggle. Two of the four are set to display:none in style sheet.  (the concern here is the toggle part not CSS)

Here are two links from JSbin: 1. This is working full and toggle all divs https://jsbin.com/piweco/1/edit?html,output   -
2. it's mine it's not toggling full. https://jsbin.com/gocebe/edit?html,css,output  - This is puzzle for me and no body so far in the course has been able to give an answer.  I hope someone can solve this puzzle. Thanks for any help.
This is html

```js
     $(".toggle").click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("selected");

       var activeDivs = $(this).text();

       $("#" + activeDivs + "cr").toggle();

     });
```

```css
 .cdcntnr {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
 }
 .cdcntnr textarea {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border: none;
   border-right: 1px solid gray;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 90%;
   padding: 5px;
 }
 .cntnrlbl {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   padding: 4px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   border-radius: 2px;
 }
 #CSScr,
 #JScr {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="toggle">
  <li class="toggle selected">HTML</li>
  <li class="toggle">CSS</li>
  <li class="toggle">JS</li>
  <li class="toggle selected" style="border:none; font-size:99%">RESULT</li>
</ul>
<div id="cntntarea">
  <div class="cdcntnr" id="HTMLcr">
    <div class="cntnrlbl">HTML</div>
    <textarea id="trea"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="cdcntnr" id="CSScr">
    <div class="cntnrlbl">CSS</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="cdcntnr" id="JScr">
    <div class="cntnrlbl">JS</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="cdcntnr" id="RESULTcr">
    <div class="cntnrlbl" id="rsltTag">RESULT</div>
    <iframe id="resultFrame"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post relevant code here at SO

Comment: remove white space from the toggle text https://jsbin.com/tohonogexo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: console log that text, it might have some space on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the text of the clicked `li` to determine which elements to `toggle` - using that text to find a specific Id

```
var activeDivs=$(this).text();
$("#"+activeDivs+"cr").toggle();
```

The elements you have look like:

```
<div class="cdcntnr" id="HTMLcr">
...
<div class="cdcntnr" id="CSScr">
.... etc
```

But in two of your toggle `li` elements you have spaces either side:

```
<li class="toggle"> CSS </li> 
<li class="toggle"> JS </li>
```

This is messing up the selector

```
$("# CSS cr").toggle(); // matches nothing
```

Remove the white spaces either side of the text in HTML, or in code

```
<li class="toggle">CSS</li>
```

or

```
var activeDivs=$(this).text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above also make sure that you bind the click events after jQuery has loaded. To make sure this, add the `onload` event of `window`

```
window.onload = function () {
            var wndwHeight = $(window).height();
            var menuHeight = $("#menu").height();
            var cdcntnrHeight = wndwHeight - menuHeight;
            $(".cdcntnr").height(cdcntnrHeight + "px");

            $("body").width($(window).width());

            $(".toggle").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
                var activeDiv = $(this).html();
                $("#" + activeDiv + "cr").toggle();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it will help hopefully.